# Set installed packages by default Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I apologize if the topic is inappropriate or has already been discussed, but gonna ask anyways.

I am new to Linux and got rid of Windows a couple of months ago and replaced it with Ubuntu. I could say that was the best decision I made in the last 1 year.

I had broke my system about a month ago and rebooted Ubuntu from the USB stick, but I think I got things wrong again now.

I have a lot of packages installed and cloned inappropriately and I get errors sometimes when running a certain tool.

I wanted to ask if somebody could tell me if there is a command or a way, which I can use in order to delete all of the installed/cloned by me packages and set the whole distro by default and simply install them again.

When I review the packages I have installed, I don't know the purpose of each of them and that's why I just want to set everything by default.

Any advise could be truly appreciated!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This seems like an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The stated problem is "*I get errors sometimes when running a certain tool*" but the question is about mass-reinstalling packages. Errors are expected when you "*have a lot of packages installed and cloned inappropriately*".

Comment: Yes, and that's why I am asking for help. In order to get things done and normally working.

Comment: You seem to be asking for 1) A System Restore feature (there currently isn't one, though one has been proposed for 21.10). 2) That apt track your installs (it does...but not the way you need), and 3) That git track your clones (yes, git does that). Advice: Back up your data and reinstall Ubuntu. Do experiments in containers instead of on your base system. Use a journal or notes to track what you install, when, why, and which instructions you followed. Stick to the Ubuntu repositories and avoid software from the dirty internet. Don't install software that lacks a method for clean uninstall.

Comment: thank you! appreciate it